# Windows 10 - No audio i/o after attempting to dual boot Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, audio, multi-boot, bluetooth, sound-card

[Similar Question](https://superuser.com/questions/732390/windows-7-8-no-sound-after-ubuntu-dual-boot). My situation is basically the same as this (5 year old) unresolved question, except with Windows 10. I tried all listed solutions here and none worked.

I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu on my Windows laptop. My laptop is the MSI GP63 Leopard 8rf. It has 2 disk drives, a 256GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. My SSD was full, so I decided to just install Ubuntu on my HDD. I created a 512GB partition on my HDD with the builtin windows tool.

I flashed Ubuntu onto a USB drive, rebooted my computer, and ran it in "Try Ubuntu" mode. I clicked the install Ubuntu icon on the desktop, and chose the partition I created for Ubuntu during installation.

Ubuntu seemed to work fine. However, when I reboot into Windows now, my audio does not work at all. The sound icon in the task bar at the bottom right says "No Audio Output Device is Installed".

Device manager: 
[image: Device Manager]

Also, I ran DxDiag. It outputs: No sound card was found.  If one is expected, you should install a sound driver provided by the hardware manufacturer. I tried downloading and installing the REALTEK Audio driver from the [MSI Site](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GP63-Leopard-8RF#down-driver&Win10%2064) but it doesn't show up in device manager? Still confused about this.

Another thing to note- I can play audio via bluetooth to my bluetooth earbuds if I pair them. However, plugging headphones into the audio jack, and the builtin speakers/microphone do not work.

Other things I have tried are using Windows "Reset This PC" tool to reset my windows installation, and getting rid of the Ubuntu partition. Neither of these did anything.

I just don't see how attempting to dual boot onto a completely separate partition could have affected audio in my Windows OS. Does anyone have any ideas? I can provide any needed info. I would really appreciate help as I've spent 8 hours today trying to debug this and made pretty much zero progress.

Comment: I think you are right, the dual boot experiment and the sound issue are very likely not connected to each other, other than indirectly.  When you were doing this, did you make bios changes?  Could you have inadvertently disabled the onboard sound system in the bios?

Comment: @Paul I did not (knowingly) make any bios changes. See my answer for what I did to finally fix this (after 9 hours of trying hundreds of things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue by doing a CMOS RESET (?), where I held the power button for 45 seconds. I still have no idea *why* this fixed the issue, or *what* caused this issue in the first place. So if anyone could explain, it would be much appreciated.